# The most Comprehensive Jquery Validator plugin?

Tags: jquery, validation

I looking for jquery validator plugin. I have done lot of searches, some plugins UI looks good, some providing low criteria's to check.

I want the most comprehensive and light weight jquery plugin for form validation.

Can anyone tell suggest me any plugin which you have used and is more comprehensive??!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) from Bassistance great customization, complete documentation and is fairly easy to use.

You can either add classes to form elements like

```
<input type="text" name="useremail" class="required email" />
```

And then just:

```
$("#myForm").validate();
```

Or you can set the rules from the jQuery like:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
      rules:{
          useremail:"required email"
      }
});
```